# Instead of looping 'while' find a pattern fetch the particular content

Tags: perl

I have a `*TXT` file (More or less 100 mb) and I have a keyword `[Main_footnn]` need to match in the `TXT` file

INPUT:

```
[START_PATIENTS]
Basic communication skills in isolation are insufficient to create
 psychosocial support.[foot2],[foot7] Interpersonal skills build
 on this basic communication skill.[foot2,4]
[END_PATIENTS]

[START_PATIENTS]
Basic communication skills in isolation are insufficient
 to create psychosocial support.[MAIN_foot2],[foot7] Interpersonal
 skills build on this basic communication skill.[foot2,4]
[END_PATIENTS]

[START_PATIENTS]
Basic communication skills in isolation are insufficient to create
 psychosocial support.[foot12],[foot17] Interpersonal skills build
 on this basic communication skill.[foot2,90]
[END_PATIENTS]
```

> Note: *The above input must be a chance to don't have a entermark might be a whole content in a single line or single entermark we have by patient to patient.*

CODE:

```
while($content=~m/\[START\_PATIENTS\]((?:(?!\[END\_PATIENTS\]).)*)\[END\_PATIENTS\]/gs)
{
    my $fulcnt = $&; my $cont = $1;
    if($cont=~m/(\[MAIN\_foot\d+\])/i)
    {
        print "$fulcnt\n";
    }
}
```

Find a `[MAIN_foot\d+\]` and fetch the particular patient contents only Instead of going by each and every patients through out the file.

> For eg. output: *[START_PATIENTS]... [MAIN_foot\d+] .... [END_PATIENTS]* need to fetch the output here.

OUTPUT:

```
[START_PATIENTS]
Basic communication skills in isolation are insufficient
 to create psychosocial support.[MAIN_foot2],[foot7] Interpersonal
 skills build on this basic communication skill.[foot2,4]
[END_PATIENTS]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Please clarify. What's the goal?

Comment: Maybe setting the record separator `$/` can make it possible to process the file patient by patient?

Comment: `[START_PATIENTS]`... [MAIN_foot\d+] .... `[END_PATIENTS]` need to get the particular content.

Comment: I have updated by question

Comment: There is any chance to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use paragraph mode

```
use warnings;
use strict;

local $/ = "";

while(<DATA>)
{
    next unless (/(\[MAIN\_foot\d+\])/i);
    print ;
}


__DATA__
[START_PATIENTS]
Basic communication skills in isolation are insufficient to create
 psychosocial support.[foot2],[foot7] Interpersonal skills build
 on this basic communication skill.[foot2,4]
[END_PATIENTS]

[START_PATIENTS]
Basic communication skills in isolation are insufficient
 to create psychosocial support.[MAIN_foot2],[foot7] Interpersonal
 skills build on this basic communication skill.[foot2,4]
[END_PATIENTS]

[START_PATIENTS]
Basic communication skills in isolation are insufficient to create
 psychosocial support.[foot12],[foot17] Interpersonal skills build
 on this basic communication skill.[foot2,90]
[END_PATIENTS]
```

For a scalar

```
foreach (split(/\[END_PATIENTS\]\n+\K/,$string))
{
    next unless (/(\[MAIN\_foot\d+\])/i);
    print ;

}
```

Comment: @ssr1012  means.? If the particular pattern is not present  loop will skips.

Comment: Don't consider with entermark its might be a whole content in a single line.

Comment: In my question the input is for only understanding purpose

Comment: Can you apply lookaround (lookbehind and lookafter) in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You could also make use of perl's range operator:

```
my @set;
my $wanted = 0;
while (<$fh>) {
    my $match = m/^\[START_PATIENTS\]$/ ... m/^\[END_PATIENTS\]$/;
    # print $match here to see what it contains
    if ($match) {
        push @set, $_;
        if (m/\[MAIN_foot\d+\]/) {
            $wanted = 1;
        }
        if ($match =~ m/E0$/) {
            # got end mark
            if ($wanted) {
                print for @set;
            }
            $wanted = 0;
            @set = ();
        }
    }
}
```

See [perldoc perlop - Range operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators)